# Worklight 6.0.0.1 iOS Native Library only for ARMv7 and not for ARMv7s and ARM64?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ibm-mobilefirst

When we build for iOS devices we seem to be limited to armv7 architecture because the sqlcipher.framework (included with worklight) isn't built for more modern architectures (armv7s, arm64)

We have to manually change the target architecture in XCode5 to enable the project to build with the worklight library. With the default settings there are "slices missing" and the build fails

Is that known and is there a plan to provide the iOS Worklight library for the modern processor architectures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a true statement, the library currently only supports armv7. All Worklight-supported Apple devices are covered under that architecture.

You can write a feature request [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25). I am unable to comment on future plans.

You could try to re-compile [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/), it's open source. Please share the outcome for future readers.

**Edit - January 30, 2014:** The following workaround is **not officially supported**. You can use the script [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/) to create an ARMv7s slice for SQLCipher and the other ARM7-only libraries your project depends on (e.g. libWorklightStaticLibProjectNative.a). Everything in your project needs to have an ARMv7s slice in order for the linker to generate the binary of your app. However, it's also worth mentioning that you will probably not see big changes in performance unless you make heavy use of floating point math, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13815761/186909).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed to confirm (I'd add this as a comment, but the SO rep isn't there for me), we had to remove the arm7s and arm64 from "Valid Architectrues".

in addition set the iOS Deployment Target to 6.0 (in my case would get link errors from the WL library when set to 7.0, though my colleague got it to build in 7.0, but the lib would crash, then working in 7.1. However in 7.1 running with arm7 caused the app to run *really* slow (note we weren't using any WL classes yet, just adding the library). Removing the WL lib and compiling for arm64 and everything was smooth again.

In our case we're on 6.1.0.1